# snap imported wrong chromium profile - lost tabs, extensions

Tags: chrome, snap

I have been using the Snap Chromium on Qubes OS (in a Fedora 23 AppVM) for a long time. Today, it broke, as it often does, so I checked what was broken:

```
bash-5.0$ snap list
Name               Version                     Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
chromium                                       1514   latest/stable  canonical✓  broken
core               16-2.49                     10859  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
core18             20210128                    1988   latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.49                        11107  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
```

and reinstalled it:

```
bash-5.0$ snap remove chromium
chromium removed
bash-5.0$ snap install chromium
chromium 89.0.4389.82 from Canonical✓ installed
```

However, when I ran Chromium, it then imported, instead of my Chromium profile from the previous snap installation, my Chromium profile from the time *before I had used the Chromium snap*:

```
Importing existing chromium profile from /home/user/.config/chromium (version 79.0.3945.117)
Import done in 4.736 s
```

It's great that I've got some ancient tabs back which I thought I'd lost... but now I'm also missing all the tabs I had open last time that weren't open way back when this profile was last updated. Plus the current set of extensions I had installed. Oh, and also the import of such an old profile didn't really work because the database has issues:

```
[4035:5622:0313/095629.735882:ERROR:database.cc(1707)] Passwords sqlite error 2067, errno 0: UNIQUE constraint failed: logins.origin_url, logins.username_element, logins.username_value, logins.password_element, logins.signon_realm, sql: INSERT INTO logins (origin_url, action_url, username_element, username_value, password_element, password_value, submit_element, signon_realm, date_created, blacklisted_by_user, scheme, password_type, times_used, form_data, date_synced, display_name, icon_url, federation_url, skip_zero_click, generation_upload_status, possible_username_pairs, id, date_last_used, moving_blocked_for) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Ideally, I would like to somehow "merge" my two profiles together, or at least the tabs, and get back the set of extensions I last had installed, and my passwords. Failing that, I'd like to switch back to the profile I last had before this import. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, snap saves a snapshot when a snap is removed:

```
bash-5.0$ snap saved
Set  Snap             Age    Version       Rev   Size    Notes
5    gnome-3-28-1804  9d13h                145       0B  auto, broken: invalid snapshot
6    chromium         87.8m  89.0.4389.82  1514   895MB  auto
bash-5.0$ snap check-snapshot 6
Snapshot #6 verified successfully.
```

So we can just exit Chromium and then do:

```
bash-5.0$ snap restore 6
Restored snapshot #6.
```

and start Chromium again, in order to restore the previous Chromium profile.